# Passing Empty Index

Tags: python, numpy

I have python code that implements something similar to the following:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,1,0,2,1,4])
ind = np.array([0,3,5])

def foo(x, ind):
    x1 = x[ind]
    x2 = np.delete(x, ind)
    return x1, x2

foo(x, ind)
```

The vector `x` is passed by a user to the function and within the function `x` is split into two vectors based on some predetermined indices in `ind`. Then, some work later in the function is performed on the vectors `x1` and `x2` (conditionally if they exist)

Conceptually there are 3 possible outcomes and currently I can make only two of them work based on how I have written this code. Outcome 1) All values are assigned to `x1` and nothing is assigned to `x2`. This is done when, for example, the value for `ind = range(6)` using the sample code above. Outcome 2) some values are assigned to `x1` and the remaining others are assigned to `x2`. This outcome is the code in the example provided above.

However, what I cannot figure out is outcome 3) all values are assigned to `x2` and nothing is assigned to `x1`. Within the context of how I have written this code, is it possible to assign some value to `ind` such that everything in the vector `x` would be assigned to `x2` and nothing would be assigned to `x1`?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: An empty list, or `range(0)`, appears to satisfy your need.

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you! I thought that would index x1 = x[0], but now I see it does not. Will mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to split numpy array like below? Then you can do this.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ind = 4
newarr = arr[0:ind]

print(newarr)
```